# Accessing state between files in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn me some React but can't seem to understand it.
How would I access this.state.planet in newMove()?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined is what I get.

Here is app.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = newPlay();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={(e) => newMove(e)}>New Move</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is logic.js

```
export const newPlay = () => ({
  planet: 'Earth',
  position: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  active: true,
  shots: 5
});

export const newMove = () => {
  let player = this.state.planet === 'Earth' ? 'Human' : 'Alien';
  console.log(player);
  this.setState({
    shots: this.state.shots++,
    active: false
  })
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how `this` and arrow functions work. That has nothing to do with React but basic JavaScript. When you call the function with `newMove(e)`, how should JavaScript know that `this` should refer to your component instance? I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Besides the issue with `this`, you don't want to update the components state based on `this.state`. Pass a function to `setState` instead. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `this` work as intended in the newMove function, you have to bind it to the class instance `this` in your constructor method.

Note that you can't use arrow notation syntax for `newMove`. Arrow functions don't support rebinding `this`. Use `function` instead.

```
export function newMove() { 
  ...
}
```

Then bind it in the App class, and use the bound `this.newMove` in your onClick prop.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = newPlay();
    this.newMove = newMove.bind(this); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.newMove}>New Move</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, even after going this way I get the error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined".  It's about the line in newMove, "let player = this.state.planet === 'Earth' ? 'Human' : 'Alien';"

Comment: @Shamaran: Seems like you forgot to updated the function definition to a non-arrow function.

Comment: Thanks guys, I posted comment and missed the update!

Comment: I don't think that it is good practice to have code external to the class modifying its state. It would be better to make `newMove` an instance method of the `App`.

Comment: @murrayju Why do you think that is bad practice? And what do you mean by "external code"? Is it ok to use class inheritance, or should we define our own `Component.setState` as well?

Comment: It is just a confusing design. It is hard to tell exactly what was done from these small snippets of code, but it looks to me like a plain function in some other file is being bound to `this`. It would be far simpler to implement `newMove` as a member of `App`. If this is logic that needs to be shared with other classes, then class inheritance or proper use of the mixin pattern would be better. Your last question sounds sarcastic, but yes it is ok.